# Get user's windows login returns NETWORK SERVICES

Tags: c#, asp.net, impersonation

I'm trying to get user's windows login from the server and all methods that I tried are returning the network's details.

I did put `<identity impersonate="true">` in my web.config but no help.

here's my webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
 <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
<identity impersonate="true"/>
<compilation targetFramework="4.5" debug="true"/>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
<sessionState timeout="20"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and here's my C# call:

```
string id1 = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string id2 = Page.User.Identity.Name;
string id3 = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name;
```

ALL 3 RETURNS EMPTY OR WITH NETWORK DETAILS. any solution??

Comment: Which user do you want - the end user of the application (those who login on to the web site), or the one under which the application is running on the server? These are entirely different users

Comment: The user that logs in to the application, the end user. thanks for the distinction.

Comment: That depends on how you are handling the login process. Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: I am not handling any login process, I'm just trying to get the windows login name as stated above.

Comment: Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your entire web site requires Windows authentication, you should make sure that Anonymous Authentication is disabled.  To do so:

1. Open the Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.
2. Select your web application and open the Authentication feature.
3. Make sure "Anonymous Authentication" is disabled and "Windows Authentication" is enabled.

Once anonymous authentication is disabled, your code for `id2` or `id3` will have the Windows logon information.  Your `id1` code will report the identity of the application pool.

If only part of your web site requires authentication and other parts do not, then your web.config should define authorization rules (and Anonymous Authentication should remain enabled).  For example, you can deny access by anonymous users to all pages by default but specifically allow anonymous access to Default.aspx.

```
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    ...
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
     ...
 </system.web>

  <location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

</configuration>
```

Windows authentication does not require your application to implement a login process.  It will issue the authentication challenge to the browser.  Some browsers like IE will supply the Windows credentials automatically and others like Firefox will present a login prompt.